# How to rebind checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkboxlist which contain 3 checkboxes whose values are check1,check2,check3. In database, in table, there is a field to save the values of checked checkboxes.

If that field conatins values check1, check2, check3 and if I use following code to bind checkboxlist, only check3 gets checked, but check1 and check2 is unchecked

```
   string[] strSourceOfInformation = dtEnquiry.Rows[0]["SourceOfInformation"].ToString().Split('&');
                for (int i = 0; i < strSourceOfInformation.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (strSourceOfInformation[i].ToString() != "")
                    {

                        foreach (ListItem htlRmItem in chkSourceOfInformation.Items)
                        {
                            if (htlRmItem.Value == strSourceOfInformation[i].ToString())
                            {
                                htlRmItem.Selected = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

how can I modify the code to get check1, check2 and check3 gets checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the .`SelectedValue` property of the checkboxlist.  This property will select the *single* value in the list that matches the value you specify, clearing all other selections.

If you want to set multiple checkboxes to be checked, you have to iterate each listitem in the `Items` collection and set the `Selected` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set SelectionMode property set to Multiple.

Comment: There is no SelectionMode property of a CheckBoxList.  A CheckBoxList is inherently multi-select.